# Relation between eigenvalues of $A^k$ and eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to prove that if $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $\lambda^k $ is an eigenvalue of $A^k$ for any positive integer $k \geq 1$. I am assuming $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. Otherwise I think the propositions is false.

The first part ($\implies$) is very easy by induction; but I am having difficulties showing it for the second part ($\Leftarrow$).

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "first part" and "second part"?

Comment: Anyway, this exercize has a trivial direction, simply putting $k=1$.

Comment: @Crostul By "part" one usually means "direction" when an iff statement is concerned. Somewhat non-obvious (and wrongly put, formally speaking) at first hand, but you'll get used to it...

Comment: Is there some special caution to be paid for the case that $\lambda < 0$ and $k$ even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think this result is true for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ also.This state is also true  for any $p(A)$.

So, here I am showing how to prove the $(\Leftarrow)$ part.

What I have is- $p(\lambda_j)$ is a eigenvalue of $p(A)$ and assume that $p$ is a $k$ degree polynomial.

$(p(A)-p(\lambda_j)I_n) = (A-\alpha_1)^{a_1} \dots (A-\alpha_i)^{a_i}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i =k$

$(p(A)-p(\lambda_j)I_n)x = (A-\alpha_1)^{a_1} \dots (A-\alpha_i)^{a_i}x$ assuming $x$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_j$.

So,
$(p(A)-p(\lambda_j)I_n)x = (A-\alpha_1I_n)^{a_1} \dots (A-\alpha_iI_n)^{a_i}x = \theta_n$

$\implies \det(p(A)-p(\lambda_j)I_n)=0$ which implies $\det((A-\alpha_l I_n)^{a_l}) = 0$ (where $l$ is an integer between $1$ to $i$).

$\det((A-\alpha_l I_n)^{a_l}) = 0 \implies \det(A-\alpha_l I_n) = 0.$ From this we can conclude that $\alpha_l$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $x$ is the corresponding eigenvector. So, $p(A)x = p(\alpha_l)x=p(\lambda_j)x$. So, $\lambda_j = \alpha_l$.

Hence, it is proved.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues and vectors of $A$ are related by :

$$Au_k=\lambda_k u_k$$

For any $n$ a positive integer greater than one, we can say :

$$A^nu_k=A^{n-1}Au_k=A^{n-1}(\lambda_k u_k)=\lambda_k A^{n-1}u_k$$

From this we easily see that :

$$A^nu_k=\lambda_k^n u_k$$

So the eigenvalues of $A^n$ are $\lambda_k^n$ and the eigenvectors are the same as those of $A$.

#### Second part.

Given only $A^nu_k=\lambda_k^n u_k$ try and prove that $\lambda_k$ is an eigenvalue of $A$

Let $Au_k=\mu_k u_k$ for some scalar $\mu_k$.

As we already know that $A^nu_k=\mu_k^nu_k$ we need only consider if $\mu_k^n = \lambda_k^n$

Strictly speaking this can only tell us that the eigenvalues of $A$ are any valid value of $(\lambda_k^n)^\frac{1}{n}$, which is *not* necessarily $\lambda_k$.

For example if $n$ was even, then we could have $\pm\lambda_k$ as eigen values of $A$.

So going from the power to the root is not always possible and the second part fails.

Comment: For the second part: You're already supposing that $u_k$ is an eigenvector of $A$, just without specifying the eigenvalue. I don't think you can assume this much.

Comment: Fair comment.  If I get some time I'll look at that.  At first thought I'd suggest that having already established the first part that seemed reasonable.  However maybe a linear combination with more than one non-zero component is also possible,